# Database displaying wrong - Webmatrix

Tags: php, mysql, database, webmatrix

I'm new to this site. I'm working on my first website that contains a database. I decided to follow a lab tutorial found online to create a website in Webmatrix and then creating a web page which displays the data. I finished creating my database but now I'm having trouble displaying them correctly. Below is the code I'm currently having trouble with. The lab code given does not quote out // the PLayer.firstname to // WHERE Players.team = Teams.teamiD"; however when I do qoute it out I don't get an error, but for some reason it displays the players to be on each team. So if I were to add another team each player would be listed 4 times instead of 5. 
Basically the database contains 2 tables with a relationship with team and teamID. When I execute a query in the database to search for player it only shows him on one team so I'm assuming the way this code is written right now its looping each player per every team. Can anyone please help me

```
   `@{  
    var db = Database.Open("Baseball");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Players, Teams";
        //@"SELECT TOP 10
          // Players.firstname,  
          // Players.lastname,  
          // Teams.teamname,  
          // Players.runscore
      // FROM Players, Teams  
       // WHERE Players.team = Teams.teamiD";

    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <title>Players standings</title>
    <style>
        h1 {font‐size: 20px;}
        table, th, td {
          border: solid 1px #bbbbbb;
          border‐collapse:collapse;
          padding:5px;
        }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Players' championship ‐ standings</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Players</th>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>runscore</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){
             <tr>
                  <td>@row.firstname  @row.lastname</td>
                 <td>@row.teamname</td>
                  <td>@row.runscore</td>
             </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </body>
    </html>`
```

I can't post a picture because of the reputation points but this is how the webpage displays :

Players' championship ‐ standings

Players Team    runscore
David  Ortiz    Orioles 134
David  Ortiz    Red Sox 134
David  Ortiz    Angels  134
David  Ortiz    Dodgers 134
Mike  Trout Orioles 132
Mike  Trout Red Sox 132
Mike  Trout Angels  132
Mike  Trout Dodgers 132
Hanley  Ramirez Orioles 102
Hanley  Ramirez Red Sox 102
Hanley  Ramirez Angels  102
Hanley  Ramirez Dodgers 102
Yasiel  Puig    Orioles 4
Yasiel  Puig    Red Sox 4
Yasiel  Puig    Angels  4
Yasiel  Puig    Dodgers 4
Josh  Hamiliton Orioles 75
Josh  Hamiliton Red Sox 75
Josh  Hamiliton Angels  75
Josh  Hamiliton Dodgers 75

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not a useful one. You've told it to get every player, and every team, and it's done that. How should it match a player with the correct team? You haven't told it, so it matches every player to every team. This is called a Cartesian join, and can be very very bad news. You need add a section on how to join the players to the correct team. You can do it two ways:

```
select *
from Players, Teams
WHERE Players.team = Teams.teamiD
```

That is the 'old-fashioned' way of doing it. The newer way, which does exactly the same thing but can be easier to read is:

```
select *
from Players p
inner join Trans t on t.Id = p.teamID
```

Look up the syntax for Joins. Joins are either inner or outer or cross, and then either left or right or full. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) is probably not a bad place to start. Then look at the docs for whichever database system you're using (I see a MySQL tag, so that would be [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)).

Comment: Thank You so much for the help that makes more sense. I'm still getting a Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected on the WHERE line. Here is what I replaced the top code with, I didn't use the join code because I had trouble understanding it and Player p .        '@{  
    var db = Database.Open("Baseball");
    var selectQueryString = @"select *
FROM Players, Teams
WHERE Players.team = Teams.teamiD;"
}'

Comment: Are you getting this error on the Database.Open, or when running query?

Comment: I'm getting this error when running the application on my web browser from the run command in WebMatrix

Comment: OK. Not too helpful. Can you debug it with WebMatrix?

Comment: Looked for that option and I found it! Looks like it was a semi colon error thank you so much! @simon-at-rcl